# Display images in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I can't get the images to display on my laravel website. I have the images in the public/img directory and have tried with

```
  src="{{ url('img/logo.png' }}"
```

and

```
   {{ HTML::image('img/logo.png') }}
```

I'm using Laravel 5.2. The url displays correctly in the web console as localhost:8000/img/logo.png but doesn't display the image

Comment: check by entering "localhost:8000/img/logo.png" in different tab

Comment: It downloads the image. But says "can't open the file" when I try to open it

Comment: ok, once try removing port number. I got into this issue once, but can't remember how I resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it was your typo when writing this post or not, can you try to change your code to:

```
src="{{ url('img/logo.png') }}"
                          ^
                          you left out a close bracket
```

If there is any changes please leave it in comment, I will try to modify my answer.

Hope it helps =)